# Can a server accept a client certificate in JKS format and refuse the same certificate in PKCS12

Tags: ssl, client-server, jks, pkcs#12

I am testing get requests for mutual TLS, and I started from a JKS certificate that was working, but when I convert it to PKCS12 it is refused by the server, and when I convert it back to JKS from PKCS12 it works again.

I am trying to understand what could be the issue.

This is what I got when debugging the handshake, juste before the refusal by the server:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-10-02 09:24:55.689 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:697|Consuming CertificateRequest handshake message (
"CertificateRequest": {
  "certificate types": [rsa_sign, dss_sign, ecdsa_sign]
  "supported signature algorithms": [rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_sha1, dsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512]
  "certificate authorities": []
}
......
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-10-02 09:24:55.746 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:299|No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-10-02 09:24:55.748 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:330|Produced client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": <empty list>
)
Exception: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://serverURL
```

Here is the command for the conversion:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore MTLS_DEV_keystore.jks -srcstoretype JKS -destkeystore MTLS_DEV_keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

When I converted back to JKS it worked with SOAP UI:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore MTLS_DEV_keystore.pfx
-srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore MTLS_DEV_keystore_converted.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass thePass
```

Comment: The server doesn't 'get the client certificate in JKS format' or in PKCS#12 format. It gets it in ASN.1 format, regardless of the source keystore format. The real question here is whether the server got the client certificate *at all.* You need to trace the client end of the handshake, which as it is Java you can do with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`, and show us whether the client certificate got sent from the PKCS#12 keystore.

Comment: I work with C#, this is why I need PKCS12 format. since it was not working in C# I tested it in SOAP UI. In the SSL Info field only the information of the server certificate is displayed, but when I use the JKS one I can see the Information of  my certificate

Comment: the JKS certificate is working well, so there is no reason to debug it in Java, and as I explained the conversion JKS->PKCS12->JKS produce a certificate that works fine

Comment: Seems to be linked to Windows system/Corporate network settings. I was able to do a successful test from my personal PC

Comment: There is a need to debug the Java code with the PKCS#12 keystore. Unless of course you aren't interested in solving the problem.

Comment: Your edit with the SSL handshake log shows that your client didn't send a certificate. So, either your PKCS#12 keystore doesn't contain a private-key entry at all, or at least it doesn't contain one that matches the specification the server sent in the `CertificateRequest` message. Show the steps you used to convert JKS to PKCS#12. In your question.

Comment: I just added the log before : "certificate authorities" is empty, is it normal?

Comment: 1. `CertificateAuthorites` being empty means the server has no truststore, or an empty one. 2. There is no such thing as a PKCS#12 certificate. There are certificates, and there are JKS or PKCS#12 keystores. Please express yourself clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the server be configured to accept a specific format?

JKS, PKCS12, PEM ... are just different containers and encoding of the same thing. These are purely used by the application to load the certificate (and key) for use within the TLS connection. What is transferred within the TLS handshake is the same though no matter which container and encoding was used by the application. That's why it is impossible for the TLS peer to make a decision based on the container or encoding used to load the certificate.